# why the two ways of adding elements of array yield different results?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the array, $$\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
1\over2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
1\over4 & 1\over2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots \\
1\over8 & 1\over4 & 1\over2 & -1 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{matrix}$$ Here $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij} = -2$, while $\sum_j\sum_ia_{ij} = 0$. Why both sums are different?

Comment: Presumably the number at the bottom left was meant to be $1/8$?

Comment: @joriki, yes it is 1/8.

Comment: More might be said if you explain why you think the sums should be the same.

Comment: @joriki, I think I may have got it. It is because the series does not converge absolutely, hence the rearrangement might yield different values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you think that the two should be the same because you are adding all the same elements, simply ordering them differently. While it is true that rearranging an *absolutely convergent* series will give you the same result, no matter how you order the elements $a_{ij}$ in your double series (in order to make it a single series) you will have a *conditionally convergent* series, which can be rearranged to converge to any real number and even diverge. This fact is known as the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_rearrangement_theorem), and is very cool.

Edit: As Robert Israel pointed out, you can't actually make this into a conditionally convergent single series as the limit of the terms can't go to $0$ (since there are infinitely many $-1$'s). So in this case the failure of rearrangement preserving the value of the series is even stronger.

Comment: Actually it will be a *divergent* series (note there are infinitely many $-1$'s).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point, editing.

Comment: For an example where you do get conditionally convergent series, try $$ \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \cr
                -\frac{1}{2\cdot 1} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \ldots\cr
-\frac{1}{3\cdot2} & -\frac{1}{3\cdot 2} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \ldots\cr
-\frac{1}{4\cdot 3} &-\frac{1}{4\cdot 3} &-\frac{1}{4\cdot 3} & \frac{1}{4} & \ldots\cr
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\cr}$$